# Optimizing Performance of Minimum Translation Vector (MTV) Calculation in SAT Collisions

Tags: javascript, game

I've implemented a Collison Manager using the Separating Axis Theorem (SAT), and I'm looking for suggestions to enhance the performance of the Minimum Translation Vector (MTV) calculation. The collider works well, but I want to explore potential optimizations, especially in the MTV calculation process.

I'm particularly interested in optimizing the way to get the collision information, which involves projections and loop iterations. Any insights, suggestions, or best practices to enhance the performance would be greatly appreciated.

**Here's the full code:** https://github.com/markvaaz/game-engine/blob/Physics/engine/engine-components/sat.js

**Here's a simplified version of the code:**

```js
collisionInformation = {
  collided: false,
  normal: new Vector(),
  overlap: Infinity,
  tangent: new Vector(),
  penetration: new Vector(),
  axis: new Vector(),
  center: new Vector(),
  vertexA: new Vector(),
  vertexB: new Vector()
};
```

#### Determines collision information between two game objects using the Separating Axis Theorem (SAT).

```js
getCollisionInformation(gameObjectA, gameObjectB) {
  if(
    gameObjectA === gameObjectB ||
    !gameObjectA.Collider.enabled ||
    !gameObjectB.Collider.enabled ||
    // AABB collision check to avoid unnecessary calculations
    !gameObjectA.Shape.isWithinBounds(gameObjectB.Shape.bounds, 1)
  ) return { collided: false };

  const CI = this.collisionInformation;

  // Reset the collision information
  CI.collided = false;
  CI.overlap = Infinity;

  // Get the maximum length of the vertices to avoid multiple loops. For example,
  // if the total vertices from A are 20 and the total vertices from B are 30,
  // it will loop 30 times instead of 50 (the some of the vertices length).
  // Although the number of calculations in this state is approximately the same,
  // it may be helpful (or not) depending on the changes.
  const lengthA = gameObjectA.Shape.vertices.length;
  const lengthB = gameObjectB.Shape.vertices.length;
  const maxLength = Math.max(lengthA, lengthB);

  for(let i = 0; i < maxLength; i++){
    if(i < lengthA && !this.getMTV(gameObjectA, gameObjectB, i)) return CI;
    if(i < lengthB && !this.getMTV(gameObjectB, gameObjectA, i)) return CI;
  }

  // Calculate the relative position vector 'center' from the center of gameObjectA to gameObjectB,
  // then check if this vector points in the opposite direction to the collision normal.
  // If so, invert the collision-related vectors in the MTV (Minimum Translation Vector) object
  // to ensure they align correctly for resolving the collision.
  const center = CI.center.set(gameObjectB.Shape.centerOfMass).sub(gameObjectA.Shape.centerOfMass);

  // Check if the center vector aligns with the collision normal (dot product < 0)
  if (center.dot(CI.normal) < 0) {
    // If the center vector points in the opposite direction to the collision normal,
    // invert the normal, tangent, and penetration vectors in the MTV to ensure proper collision resolution.
    CI.normal.negate();
    CI.tangent.negate();
    CI.penetration.negate();
  }

  return CI;
}
```

#### Calculate the Minimum Translation Vector (MTV) between two sets of vertices.

```js
getMTV(gameObjectA, gameObjectB, index){
  const vertices = gameObjectA.Shape.vertices;
  const position = gameObjectA.Shape.centerOfMass;
  const CI = this.collisionInformation;
  const vertexA = CI.vertexA.set(vertices[index]).add(position);
  const vertexB = CI.vertexB.set(vertices[index + 1] ?? vertices[0]).add(position);


  // Calculate the axis perpendicular to the current edge.
  const axis = CI.axis.set(-(vertexB.y - vertexA.y), vertexB.x - vertexA.x).normalize();

  // Get the overlap along the axis.
  const overlap = this.getOverlap(axis, gameObjectA, gameObjectB);

  // If there's no overlap, update the MTV to indicate no collision.
  if(overlap === 0) return CI.collided = false;

  // If the absolute overlap is less than the current minimum overlap in the MTV,
  // update the MTV with information about the current collision.
  if(Math.abs(overlap) < CI.overlap){
    CI.collided = true;

    CI.overlap = Math.abs(overlap);

    CI.normal.set(axis.x, axis.y);

    CI.tangent.set(-CI.normal.y, CI.normal.x);

    CI.penetration.set(CI.normal.x * overlap, CI.normal.y * overlap);
  }

  return CI.collided;
}
```

#### Calculate the overlap between two sets of vertices along a specified axis through projections.

```js
getOverlap(axis, gameObjectA, gameObjectB){
  let minA = Infinity;
  let maxA = -Infinity;
  let minB = Infinity;
  let maxB = -Infinity;

  const verticesA = gameObjectA.Shape.vertices;
  const verticesB = gameObjectB.Shape.vertices;
  const positionA = gameObjectA.Shape.centerOfMass;
  const positionB = gameObjectB.Shape.centerOfMass;
  const lengthA = verticesA.length;
  const lengthB = verticesB.length;
  const CI = this.collisionInformation;

  const maxLength = Math.max(lengthA, lengthB);

  // Loop through vertices to calculate projections and find minimum and maximum values
  for (let i = 0; i < maxLength; i++) {
    if(i < lengthA){
      const vertex = CI.vertexA.set(verticesA[i]).add(positionA);
      const projection = axis.dot(vertex);
      minA = Math.min(minA, projection);
      maxA = Math.max(maxA, projection);
    }

    if(i < lengthB){
      const vertex = CI.vertexB.set(verticesB[i]).add(positionB);
      const projection = axis.dot(vertex);
      minB = Math.min(minB, projection);
      maxB = Math.max(maxB, projection);
    }
  }

  // Check for separation along the axis, return 0 if no overlap
  if (minA > maxB || minB > maxA) return 0;

  // Calculate the overlap between the two projections
  return Math.min(maxB - minA, maxA - minB);
}
```